# deploy hashicorp vault without persistent storage in openshift

Tags: openshift, hashicorp-vault, persistent-volumes, openshift-enterprise

How to deploy the hashicorp vault in openshift with out using persistent volumes(PV)?

In the openshift cluster as a normal user(not a cluster admin),need to deploy the vault server. I followed the [URL](https://github.com/openlab-red/hashicorp-vault-for-openshift) but it has persistent volumes (/vault/file) in vault.yaml file in it, which requires permission for my account to create persistent container but I do not have enough permission for my account. so i removed the pv mount paths in the vault-config.json like below, but I am seeing the below error.

```
{"backend": 
    {"file": 
        {"path": "/tmp/file"}
    }, 
...
...
}
```

Is it possible to create the vault server without PV, like using the local file path (/tmp/file) as backend storage as a normal user?

What is the alternative way to deploy vault in openshift without PV to deploy hashicorp vault?

Below is the error when run with pv,

```
--> Scaling vault-1 to 1
-->  FailedCreate: vault-1 Error creating: pods "vault-1-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]
error: update acceptor rejected vault-1: pods for rc 'dev-poc-environment/vault-1' took longer than 600 seconds to become available
```

Comment: You could use raft instead, but it's only in preview: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/raft.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to deploy the hashicorp vault in openshift with out using
>   persistent volumes(PV)?

You can use **In-Memory storage backend** as mentioned [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/in-memory.html). So your **vault config** looks something like this:

```
$cat config.hcl
disable_mlock = true
storage "inmem" {}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 0
  tls_cert_file = "/etc/service/vault-server/vault-server.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/etc/service/vault-server/vault-server.key"
}

ui = true
max_lease_ttl = "7200h"
default_lease_ttl = "7200h"
api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
```

But with this **data/secrets are not persistent**.

**Another way is to add a file path to the storage**, so that all the secrets which are encrypted stored at the mentioned path.

so now your config changes to

```
storage "file" {
    path = "ANY-PATH"
}
```

**POINTS TO BE NOTED HERE:**

1. Path defined should have **permissions to write/read data/secrets**
2. This could be **any path that is inside the container**, just to avoid dependency on persistence volume.

But **what is the problem with this model**? When the **container restarts, all the data will be lost as the container doesn't store data**.

> No High Availability – the Filesystem backend does not support high
>   availability.

So **what should be the ideal solution**? Anything that makes our **data highly available**, which is achieved by using **[dedicated backend storage](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/index.html) using a database.**

For simplicity, let us take [PostgreSQL](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/postgresql.html) as backend storage.

```
storage "postgresql" {
  connection_url = "postgres://user123:secret123!@localhost:5432/vault"
}
```

so now config looks something like this:

```
$ cat config.hcl
disable_mlock = true

storage "postgresql" {
  connection_url = "postgres://vault:vault@vault-postgresql:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 0
  tls_cert_file = "/etc/service/vault-server/vault-server.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/etc/service/vault-server/vault-server.key"
}

ui = true
max_lease_ttl = "7200h"
default_lease_ttl = "7200h"
api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
```

So choosing **backend storage helps you to persist your data even if the container restarts**.

As you are specifically **looking for a solution in openshift**, **create a postgresSQL container using template provided** and make vault point it to it using the service name as explanied in the above config.hcl

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. I will try your solution using postgresSQL.